# Prevent permanent deletion of files in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, recycle-bin

First, I'm running Windows XP Home Edition Service Pack 3.

Is there any way to disable the permanent delete? Normally, deleted files go to the Recycle Bin. Can I disable the bypass-recycle-bin-delete thing? Or change the permanent-delete command from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to something else?

Basically, I want to require that all files have to pass through the Recycle Bin in order to be deleted.

Comment: even if there was a way the user could still empty the recycle bin.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to disable this key-combination.

1. Right-click an empty spot on your desktop or in a folder of your choice.
2. In the menu that appears, select New -> AutoHotkey Script. (Alternatively, select New -> Text Document.)
3. Type a name for the file, ensuring that it ends in .ahk. For example: Test.ahk
4. Right-click the file and choose Edit Script.
5. On a new blank line you have to insert this script in the file.

   +Delete::Send {Delete}

This will block the shift + delete - keystroke and will only execute the command like just the "del" key was pressed.

You can also add a line that will disable the possibility to permanent delete this in context-menu. **But that will also block any other shift + rightclick-operation and won't work if the user first pressed the shift-key. **

```
+RButton::return
```

6. Save and close the file.
7. Double-click the file to launch it. A new icon appears in the taskbar notification area.
8. Test your script.
9. To exit or edit the script, right-click the green "H" icon in the taskbar notification area.

[Tutorial-source](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm)

But as mentioned in the comments, the user can still delete the files from the recycle-bin. And also he can still delete it if he first rightclick and than presses shift. So it's just to prevent users a bit.

Comment: This is the best know solution. I would however completely block the shift+delete (with this method) so you'll learn not to use it anymore (for if you're behind system without this solution). Also, this won't work if you delete via right-click and then clicking "Delete" while holding the shift.

Comment: Your script is not correct. It should be `+Delete::Send {Delete}`. Yours gives an error.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've edited my answer. Also i've added the possibility to disable the shift + right-click. Thanks. :)

Comment: The right-click and then Delete in context menu + shift doesn't work. Its not the Right-click that needs to be addressed but the left-click **on Delete** with Shift. You can't do that in AutoHotKey.

Comment: Edited it again. Sry I'm on mac at the moment. But the other script: `+RBUTTON::return`` works?

Comment: Nope, you can't catch the Right-click + choosing Delete with Shift in AutoHotKey (So you can delete that, or just leave a mention of it). The `+Delete` should be sufficient as answer on this question.

Comment: Strange .That should work. :S

Comment: Aaa, now i see. I do **first** Right-click and then **shift** while choosing "Delete". Your way is blocking the complete Shift+Right-click. But i pressed the Shift **after** the right-click. So, yes, this works as long as you hold the shift **before** the right-click. (+1'd)

Comment: Unfortunately, autohotkey can't check if the context-menu was opened. I've added the second script-line again, but added also a "not-so-safe"-warning. Thanks for your help.